# Matlab - Periodic tiling of a surface

Tags: matlab

I have a surface that is representative of a barnacle distribution (randomly generated), however some of the points are generated off the desired area. I would like for any points that are generated off the surface to reappear on the other side.

This is so that if you imagine this surface as a 'tile', when infinite tiles are laid down there are no jumps or gaps, it is periodic.

```
clear

n_gaussians=20;         % number of barnacles
gaussians=0;            
sigma=1;                % std deviation
mindist=0.8*sigma;      % if distance is smaller than this gaussians "collide" and are not plotted
height=0.3;             % height of the barnacle

[x,y]= meshgrid(-5:0.05:5,-5:0.05:5);
used=[];
Z=zeros(size(x));
while gaussians<n_gaussians

    xm=(rand(1)-0.5)*10;
    ym=(rand(1)-0.5)*10;
    notvalid=0;

        for ii=1:size(used,2)
        % if we are too close to any point.
       if norm([xm-used(1,ii),ym-used(2,ii)])<mindist
           notvalid=1; % do not add this gauusian
       end
    end
    if notvalid
        continue
    end
    used(:,end+1)=[xm;ym];
    Zaux = height/sigma*exp(-5*((x-xm).^2+(y-ym).^2)/sigma.^2)-0.1;
    Zaux(Zaux<0)=0;
    Z=Z+Zaux;
    gaussians=gaussians+1;
end

surf(x,y,Z);
axis equal
shading interp
```

This picture hopefully explains what is needed:

[image]

I also need to keep the spacing though, so if xm,ym are within a distance of the guassian distribution on the other side of the plot, they need to be discounted.

I have tried to get this to work but I cannot seem to find a way. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to run the same code but on a periodical space that is 9 times bigger (3x3) times your space. Then , instead of placing 1 barnacle for a given Gaussian, place 9 of them periodically with the error checking everywhere. Then take the central square as your output. (Don't know if it's clear)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to wrap axes around edge values, via `mod`. With your tacit permission :-) I took the liberty of re-writing your code:

```
n_gauss = 20;
k_gauss = 0;            
sigma   = 1;
mindist = 0.8*sigma;
height  = 0.3;
L       = 5;
dL      = 0.05;

[x,y] = meshgrid(-L:dL:L, -L:dL:L);
used  = NaN(2,n_gauss);
Z     = zeros(size(x));
while k_gauss < n_gauss
        xm = (rand-0.5)*2*L;
        ym = (rand-0.5)*2*L;

        valid = true;
        for k = 1:k_gauss
                Dx = mod(abs(used(1,k)-xm),2*L);
                Dy = mod(abs(used(2,k)-ym),2*L);
                if norm([Dx;Dy]) < mindist
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                end;
        end;

        if valid
                Dx = mod(x-xm,2*L)-L;
                Dy = mod(y-ym,2*L)-L;
                Zaux = height/sigma ...
                     * exp(-5*(Dx.^2 + Dy.^2)/sigma.^2) - 0.1;
                Zaux(Zaux<0) = 0;
                Z = Z + Zaux;

                k_gauss = k_gauss+1;
                used(:,k_gauss) = [xm;ym];
        end;
end

surf(x,y,Z);
axis equal;
shading interp;
```

Comment: That is a lot clearer! This certainly works for periodic boundary conditions, however the minimum distance is no longer observed, I keep getting overlap on the output. 

http://i.imgur.com/LfsH2PN.jpg

Comment: @andy-m I discovered the mistake, I'm going to correct the code

Comment: @andy-m Code is fixed.

Comment: @andy-m Glad that I could help.